# Buffer is not defined al decodificar token de jwt-simple en angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, jwt

### Descripción del problema

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con Angular 15 y trato de usar un token de jwt-simple para mantener la sesión del usuario abierta, al enviar la petición de inicio de sesión al servidor si la respuesta es positiva se envía al usuario un token desde el back y se guarda en el localStorage, a la hora de volver a iniciar sesión se recupera el token del localStorage, se decodifica y se evalúa la fecha de expiración, si aún es válido se redirigirá al usuario directo a la página principal, mientras que si ha expirado se le pedirá volver a autenticarse, el problema es que al intentar decodificar el token con la función decode de jwt-simple me sale "ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined".

### Soluciones que se intentaron

Ya instalé la librería de buffer, la importé en mi archivo y la mandé como parámetro del constructor, lo tengo añadido como proveedor en el módulo principal, e incluso creé el archivo pollyfill.ts en la carpeta src y especifiqué la ruta en la sección builds del angular.json, pero me sigue dando error y no sé que más hacer

**P.D.: Sí, ya revisé que el token me llegue correctamente y que se pueda recuperar del localStorage**

### Código

**Código del back que genera el token**

```javascript
'use strict'

import jwt from 'jwt-simple'
import moment from 'moment/moment.js'

export const secret_key = 'clave secreta'

export function crearTokenDeSesion(result) {

    const payload2 = {
        sub: result.id,
        name: result.nombre,
        last_name: result.apellido_p,
        email: result.email,
        iat: moment().unix(),
        exp: moment().add(6, 'hours')
    }

    return jwt.encode(payload2, secret_key)
}
```

**Código que envía el token al front**

```javascript
export function iniciarSesion(req, res, next) {

    const email = req.body.email
    const password = req.body.password
    const keepSession = req.body.keepSession

    const validateEmail = emailRegex.test(email)
    const validatePswd = pswdRegex.test(password)

    //console.log([email, password])

    if (!email || !password) {
        res.status(400).json('Por favor rellene todos los campos para continuar')
    } else if (!validateEmail) {
        res.status(400).send('El correo no es válido')
    } else if (!validatePswd) {
        res.status(400).send(`La contraseña debe tener 8 caracteres como mínimo y debe contener al menos una mayúscula y un número, 
            además no puede llevar caracteres especiales excepto "-" ó "_"`)
    } else {
        let query = 'SELECT email, password, verificado FROM profesores WHERE email = ?'
        conexion.query(query, [email], (err, resultq) => {
            const verificado = resultq[0].verificado
            if (err) {
                return next(err)
            } else if (resultq.length == 0) {
                res.status(404).send(`El usuario con el correo: ${email} no existe`)
            } else if (verificado == 0) {
                res.status(401).send('Su correo no ha sido verificado, solicite un token de verificación e intentelo de nuevo')
            } else {
                const user = resultq[0]
                const hash = user.password
                bcrypt.compare(password, hash, (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return next(err)
                    } else if (result) {
                        if(keepSession==true){
                            const sessionToken = crearTokenDeSesion(user)
                            const decodedToken = jwt.decode(sessionToken, secret_key)
                             res.status(200).json({
                                mensaje: 'Inicio de sesión exitoso',
                                usuario: user.email,
                                token: sessionToken
                            })
                        } else{
                            res.status(200).json({
                                mensaje: 'Inicio de sesión exitoso',
                                usuario: user.email,
                            })
                        }
                    } else {
                        res.status(401).send('Contraseña incorrecta')
                    }
                })
            }

        })
    }
}
```

**Código que recibe el token, lo guarda, lo recupera y lo decodifica**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable, catchError, map } from 'rxjs'
import { decode } from 'jwt-simple'
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LoginServiceService {

  //Creamos un nuevo objeto de tipo url con la URL base de nuestro servidor
  public apiUrl: URL = new URL('http://localhost:8000/api')

  //Añadimos un objeto de tipo HttpClient como parámetro del constructor
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private buffer: Buffer) {

  }

  //Declaramos el método iniciar sesión que recibe dos parámetros (email y password) de tipo string y devuelve un objeto de tipo Observable<any>
  iniciarSesion(email: string, password: string, session: boolean): Observable<any> {
    //Establecemos en los encabezados el tipo de contenido como una aplicación en formato json
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })
    //Mandamos los datos en el cuerpo de la petición
    const body = { email: email, password: password, keepSession: session }

    //retornamos una petición http con el método post, le pasamos como parámetros la ruta del servidor, el cuerpo de la petición y los encabezados
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/iniciarSesion`, body, { headers: headers })

      //Le encadenamos el método pipe para combinar los operadores map y cacthError sin necesidad de un if else
      .pipe(
        //invocamos el método map, obtenemos el token de la respuesta, lo guardamos en el almacenamiento local y retornamos el objeto response
        map(response => {
          const token: string = response.token
          localStorage.setItem('token', token)
          console.log(token)
          return response
        }),

        //Si ocurre un error, lo imprimimos en consola y lo arrojamos
        catchError(error => {
          console.error(`Error en la petición de inicio de sesión: ${JSON.stringify(error.message)}`)
          throw error
        })
      )
  }


  //Este método recupera el token del localStorage y devuelve un string o un null en caso de que no se encuentre el objeto
  getToken(): string | null {
    return localStorage.getItem('token')
  }

  //Esto elimina el token de localStorage
  cerrarSesion(): void {
    localStorage.removeItem('token')
  }


  //Esto comprueba la validez del token y devuelve verdadero o falso según el caso
  autenticar(): boolean {

    const token: string | null = this.getToken() //recuperamos el token mediante el método getToken y lo guardamos en la constante token
    let result: boolean //creamos una variable llamada result para devolverla en la función y cuyo valor dependerá de la validez del token

    if (!token) {
      return false //Si el token es nulo, retornamos falso directamente
    } else {

      try {

        //De lo contrario, tratamos de decodificar el token y comparamos su fecha de expiración con la fecha actual
        const decodedToken: any = decode(token, "clave secreta")
        console.log(decodedToken)
        const expiredToken: boolean = decodedToken.exp >= Date.now()
        console.log(
          {
            "fecha_expiracion": decodedToken.exp,
            "fecha_actual": Date.now()
          }
        )

        //Si el token ha expirado, result será igual a falso, de lo contrario será verdadero
        expiredToken ? result = false : result = true

        //retornamos la variable result
        return result
      }

      //Si hay un error, lo imprimimos en consola y retornamos falso
      catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error al decodificar el token: ${error}`)
        return false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No es necesario usar momentjs para establecer la expiración de un JWT token, mientras que en lugar de declarar variables para cada parte del request, simplemente puedes hacer `const { email, password, keepSession } = req.body;` mientras que `secret_key` ya no es tan secreta, crea un archivo `.env` para agregar claves, urls, strings de conexión, etc. para evitar tenerlos declarados directamente en el código.

Comment: Tres observaciones: 1. Esa biblioteca que mencionas está hecha para node.js lo que no garantiza que funcione en el frontend. 2. Cuando decodifiques JWT en el frontent no necesitas validarlo con su llave privada, el frontend no debe conocer esa clave por ningún motivo. 3. La biblioteca es antigua, hace años que no se actualiza, es mejor buscar una más reciente.

Comment: @Lobos que biblioteca me recomiendas como alternativa?